# in C# what does 'bool = bool != true' mean?

Tags: c#, boolean-logic

In my hunt for some help to a problem I was having I came across this:

```
p.Enabled = p.Enabled != true;
```

What exactly does this mean? Ive never seen it before,

nb: the preceeding line was `var p = this.PageRepository.GetPage(id);`

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote C#, but it looks like it's the equivalent of `p.Enabled = !p.Enabled;`.

Comment: p.Enabled = p.Enabled 
this is where you saying that p.Enabled will take the value of  p.Enabled (which does not make sence). Then you are saying it should not be equal to tue ; therefore false

Comment: Wow, ten duplicate answers to this question (including those two "comment" answers above).  Me thinks some people should be deleting their answers.

Comment: @Andrew: dead wrong.  != is a comparison operator, not an assignment operator.

Comment: I like siride's answer as the most complete. To break it down, read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx for operator precedence.

Comment: It's a one iteration of: *This statement is false.*

Comment: is p.Enabled a `bool` or a `bool?`?

Comment: Excellent, thanks for all the insight...

Comment: Is there any good reason for someone to write the code that way, as opposed to the straightforward formulation?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When `p.Enabled` is a normal `bool`, as Enabled properties usually are,

```
p.Enabled = p.Enabled != true;
```

is the same as

```
p.Enabled = ! p.Enabled;
```

in other words: it flips or toggles `p.Enabled`.

Now when Enabled is a `bool?` , shorthand for `Nullable<bool>` , the results are different:

```
! ((bool?) null)           -> null
((bool?) null) != true     -> true
```

So `p.Enabled = p.Enabled != true` will set `true` when the old value was `false` or `null`.

Comment: Only true if `p.Enabled` is set. Your code won't work if `p.Enabled = null`.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen - I don't know this Page class but in general IsEnabled properties aren't nullable.

Comment: KristianAntonsen makes an important distinction... strictly speaking, the two statements are not equivalent. It helps us understand how that line made it into the code base (some programmer trying to handle the null case of p.Enabled).

Comment: which is not to say that this answer in incorrect or that the expression shouldn't be refactored

Answer (score 32):

It's an awkwardly written bool toggle switch. Each call toggles the state from true to false. I'd have written it:

```
p.Enabled = !p.Enabled;
```

Edit - I suppose I should say, awkwardly written in my opinion only.

Comment: Don't worry, it *is* awkwardly written.

Comment: I think awkwardly written is an understatement. It's a perfect example of someone adding complexity for the sake of making themselves feel smart OR not knowing what negation is. Either way bad sign.

Answer (score 19):

So many answers ... I just want to break it down a little bit more:

```
p.Enabled = p.Enabled != true;
```

Is semantically equivalent to:

```
var IN = p.Enabled;
var OUT = IN != true;
p.Enabled = OUT;
```

So:

```
p.Enabled -> IN     IN != true      OUT -> p.Enabled
---------------     -------------   ----------------
true                true  != true   false
false               false != true   true
(if nullable) null  null  != true   true
```

Thus, from the [Truth Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table), it can be seen it is the same* as the [logical not (`!`) operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) and can be rewritten as:

```
p.Enabled = !p.Enabled;
```

(I would imagine that most [experienced] programmers prefer this latter form as it's a fairly common idiom.)

Happy coding.

---

*Note the addition of `null` as the *third* input state in case of `bool?` (aka `Nullable<bool>`) types. (Thanks, Thomas Mayfield ;-)

Answer (score 10):

It's the same as `p.Enabled = !p.Enabled;`, the opposite of `p.Enabled`.

Answer (score 9):

The test `p.Enabled != true` is evaluated. The result of that (which is a boolean) is assigned to `p.Enabled`. So if `p.Enabled` is true, then `p.Enabled` will be set to false. Another way to say this is `p.Enabled = !p.Enabled`. That is, it's basically inverting the value of `p.Enabled`.

Answer (score 8):

if `p.Enabled` is a plain `bool` it's equivalent to `p.Enabled = !p.Enabled`. i.e. it toggles `p.Enabled`.

But if `p.Enabled` is a nullable bool, it will map `null` and `false` to `true`, and map `true` to `false`. But I'd prefer writing `p.Enabled = !(p.Enabled ?? true)` in that case.

If `p.Enabled` is a custom type with overloaded implicit conversion operators, anything might happen.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially this would flip the value of p.Enabled.  So if it were true then `p.Enabled != true` evaluates to false, and then that false value gets assigned to `p.Enabled = false`.  And it would work the other way around if p.Enabled were false.

It might make more sense if it were written like so:

```
p.Enabled = !(p.Enabled);
```

Answer (score 3):

Think of it this way:

```
p.Enabled = (p.Enabled != true);
```

Now, `(p.Enabled != true)` evaluates to a `bool`, which can then be assigned to another `bool` variable.

Answer (score 3):

The line evaluates `p.Enabled != true`, which is `false` if p.Enabled is true and `true` if p.Enabled is false. In other words, a very awkward way of writing

```
p.Enabled = !p.Enabled
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
bool cond = (p.Enabled != true);
if (cond == true) 
{
  p.Enabled = cond; // = true
}
else
{
  p.Enabled = cond; // = false
}
```